# Redis & Sentinel communication

Tags: php, node.js, web-services, laravel, redis

I want to broadcast some events like notifications from my php server to the client.
I want the service to run locally so I decided to go with Redis.
So I installed the server and started setting Laravel and nodejs.

I decided to test my work so I started the Redis server.
Wanting to see what the server does I open the console with monitor parameter.

And I saw this:
[image]

As you can tell I don't know much about Redis.
Can anyone tell me what it is going on here?
Is this normal and is it going raise my server's payload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is normal that Sentinel pings your Redis instances every 2 seconds. The publish commands correspond to Sentinel broadcasting its own view on the configuration of the instances.

See http://redis.io/topics/sentinel for more information.

Note that Redis can easily support 100000 ops/s, so a few op/s for high-availability monitoring is negligible. It will not raise your server payload in a measurable way.